# How to read symbolicated crash log?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, crash, symbolicate

Today my first app was rejected from testflight, because it crashed on start. But I cannot replicate it, because I do not have an Iphone, and in the simulator it works. I managed to symbolicate the crash log, but cant figure out how to read it. Could you please explain what this means and how it is read?

have to dump some text because its longer than the max. allowed post length:

```
{"app_name":"GalShare.iOS","timestamp":"2020-04-07 10:53:38.00 -0700","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"853017b6-7ddd-3117-8bcc-9e70eccb1beb","adam_id":1506214268,"build_version":"1.0.3","bundleID":"com.digitalcreations.gallery-share","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.4 (17E255)","incident_id":"DE12E4AE-50A7-4B53-82F5-3552060EECE1","name":"GalShare.iOS"}
Incident Identifier: DE12E4AE-50A7-4B53-82F5-3552060EECE1
CrashReporter Key:   41f313b53eec883ec04c9b214b4954527b163a77
Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
Process:             GalShare.iOS [656]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5AF26889-625E-4576-8138-D238936BD490/GalShare.iOS.app/GalShare.iOS
Identifier:          com.digitalcreations.gallery-share
Version:             1.0.3 (1.0.0)
AppStoreTools:       11E146
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.digitalcreations.gallery-share [648]


Date/Time:           2020-04-07 10:53:37.9728 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-04-07 10:53:37.8008 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.4 (17E255)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_407  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019abb8df0 0x19ab92000 + 159216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aad8930 0x19aad6000 + 10544
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019aa66934 0x19a9f0000 + 485684
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019aa668c0 0x19a9f0000 + 485568
4   GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103db7e94 print_callback(char const*, int) + 23461524 (runtime.m:1218)
5   GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103da69e8 monoeg_g_logv_nofree + 23390696 (goutput.c:150)
6   GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103da6a38 monoeg_g_log + 23390776 (goutput.c:165)
7   GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103bed0d8 load_aot_module + 21582040 (aot-runtime.c:2225)
8   GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103c4cde8 mono_assembly_invoke_load_hook_internal + 21974504 (assembly.c:1941)
9   GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103c4df30 mono_assembly_request_load_from + 21978928 (assembly.c:3178)
10  GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103c4da2c mono_assembly_request_open + 21977644 (assembly.c:2639)
11  GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103c50084 mono_assembly_open + 21987460 (assembly.c:2987)
12  GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103db7f84 xamarin_initialize + 23461764 (runtime.m:1325)
13  GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103dbee54 xamarin_main + 23490132 (monotouch-main.m:434)
14  GalShare.iOS                    0x00000001027a5b5c main + 318300 (main.m:110)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019abc31ec 0x19abc2000 + 4588

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aadf9c0 0x19aad6000 + 39360

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aadf9c0 0x19aad6000 + 39360

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aadf9c0 0x19aad6000 + 39360

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aadf9c0 0x19aad6000 + 39360

Thread 5 name:  SGen worker
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019abb8bc0 0x19ab92000 + 158656
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aadb1e4 0x19aad6000 + 20964
2   GalShare.iOS                    0x0000000103d839bc thread_func + 23247292 (sgen-thread-pool.c:196)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aad78fc 0x19aad6000 + 6396
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019aadf9d4 0x19aad6000 + 39380

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000600
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x07a058f6e92ad1f0  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000179f41
   x12: 0x0000000111904000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0x00000000bd7a0741  x15: 0x00000000000072bf
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001db50e808  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x000000010443a120  x22: 0x00000002834fe900  x23: 0x0000000103ed4a88
   x24: 0x0000000105640000  x25: 0x000000010567cb5f  x26: 0x0000000103e8b2d1  x27: 0x0000000105653640
   x28: 0x00000002818e05e0   fp: 0x000000016d6a6420   lr: 0x000000019aad8930
    sp: 0x000000016d6a6400   pc: 0x000000019abb8df0 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x102758000 - 0x103eaffff GalShare.iOS arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5AF26889-625E-4576-8138-D238936BD490/GalShare.iOS.app/GalShare.iOS
0x104164000 - 0x10416ffff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x104394000 - 0x1043fbfff dyld arm64e   /usr/lib/dyld
0x19a9a4000 - 0x19a9bafff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x19a9bb000 - 0x19a9eefff libxpc.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x19a9ef000 - 0x19a9effff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x19a9f0000 - 0x19aa6efff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x19aa6f000 - 0x19aaacfff libdispatch.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x19aaad000 - 0x19aacefff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x19aacf000 - 0x19aad5fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x19aad6000 - 0x19aae0fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x19aae1000 - 0x19ab12fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x19ab13000 - 0x19ab7bfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x19ab7c000 - 0x19ab91fff libc++abi.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x19ab92000 - 0x19abc1fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x19abc2000 - 0x19abf6fff libdyld.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x19abf7000 - 0x19abfffff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x19ac00000 - 0x19ac5dfff libc++.1.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x19ac5e000 - 0x19ac9ffff libsystem_info.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x19aca0000 - 0x19b01dfff CoreFoundation arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x19b01e000 - 0x19b088fff SystemConfiguration arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x19b089000 - 0x19b354fff Foundation arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x19b355000 - 0x19b387fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x19b388000 - 0x19b50afff CoreServices arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
0x19b50b000 - 0x19b56cfff libSparse.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x19b56d000 - 0x19ba66fff ImageIO arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x19ba67000 - 0x19ba69fff ConstantClasses arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x19ba6a000 - 0x19bc03fff CoreText arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x19bc04000 - 0x19bd41fff Security arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x19bd42000 - 0x19bde8fff IOKit arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x19bde9000 - 0x19be20fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x19be21000 - 0x19be7ffff libprotobuf.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
0x19be80000 - 0x19be92fff libprotobuf-lite.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libprotobuf-lite.dylib
0x19be93000 - 0x19c0f2fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x19c11d000 - 0x19c163fff WirelessDiagnostics arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
0x19c164000 - 0x19c1a0fff libAWDSupport.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libAWDSupport.dylib
0x19c1a1000 - 0x19c5f0fff CoreAudio arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x19c5f1000 - 0x19c8cafff CoreImage arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x19c8cb000 - 0x19c9befff LanguageModeling arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x19c9bf000 - 0x19ca05fff Lexicon arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Lexicon
0x19ca06000 - 0x19cb8cfff libsqlite3.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x19cb8d000 - 0x19cbbffff MobileKeyBag arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x19cbc0000 - 0x19cbc9fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x19cbca000 - 0x19cdb6fff CoreDuet arm64e   
0x1b945b000 - 0x1b9461fff Netrb arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x1c10bc000 - 0x1c10c6fff HID arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HID.framework/HID
0x1c10f3000 - 0x1c112efff libGLImage.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1c153b000 - 0x1c154cfff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x1c154d000 - 0x1c1561fff Engram arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Engram.framework/Engram
0x1c15db000 - 0x1c1615fff DataDetectorsNaturalLanguage arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsNaturalLanguage.framework/DataDetectorsNaturalLanguage
0x1c191d000 - 0x1c1925fff FSEvents arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FSEvents.framework/FSEvents
0x1c1926000 - 0x1c19a4fff CoreDAV arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDAV.framework/CoreDAV
0x1c231b000 - 0x1c232bfff RemoteTextInput arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RemoteTextInput.framework/RemoteTextInput
0x1c2354000 - 0x1c2383fff iCalendar arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x1c23a0000 - 0x1c23a9fff CloudPhotoServices arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudPhotoServices.framework/CloudPhotoServices
0x1c23e9000 - 0x1c23fdfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x1c2684000 - 0x1c2692fff CoreAUC arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x1c307a000 - 0x1c30c0fff PhysicsKit arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x1c30c1000 - 0x1c3114fff CorePrediction arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePrediction.framework/CorePrediction
0x1c352e000 - 0x1c3578fff SafariSafeBrowsing arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariSafeBrowsing.framework/SafariSafeBrowsing
0x1c3937000 - 0x1c39aefff HomeSharing arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x1c3a40000 - 0x1c3a5efff GenerationalStorage arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x1c3ac3000 - 0x1c3acefff PersonaKit arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersonaKit.framework/PersonaKit
0x1c3efa000 - 0x1c3efffff kperf arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/kperf.framework/kperf
0x1c40e0000 - 0x1c411afff libpcap.A.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x1c4462000 - 0x1c4507fff libvDSP.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1c4508000 - 0x1c4533fff vCard arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/vCard.framework/vCard
0x1c457c000 - 0x1c4609fff SampleAnalysis arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SampleAnalysis.framework/SampleAnalysis
0x1c460a000 - 0x1c4617fff IntentsFoundation arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntentsFoundation.framework/IntentsFoundation
0x1c4809000 - 0x1c4896fff MediaPlatform arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaPlatform.framework/MediaPlatform
0x1c4897000 - 0x1c4b67fff MediaLibraryCore arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaLibraryCore.framework/MediaLibraryCore
0x1c4bcc000 - 0x1c4c05fff PhotosImagingFoundation arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotosImagingFoundation.framework/PhotosImagingFoundation
0x1c4c06000 - 0x1c4c28fff MediaConversionService arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaConversionService.framework/MediaConversionService
0x1c4c29000 - 0x1c4c47fff MediaStream arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x1c4c48000 - 0x1c4d48fff CoreMediaStream arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x1c4e68000 - 0x1c4e68fff Accelerate arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x1c4e69000 - 0x1c51a0fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x1c51a1000 - 0x1c51a5fff libQuadrature.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib
0x1c51a6000 - 0x1c51fffff libvMisc.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1c5200000 - 0x1c5200fff vecLib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1c5584000 - 0x1c55aafff GLKit arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit
0x1c55ab000 - 0x1c55d7fff GSS arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
0x1c55ea000 - 0x1c561cfff MPSCore arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSCore.framework/MPSCore
0x1c561d000 - 0x1c569afff MPSImage arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSImage.framework/MPSImage
0x1c569b000 - 0x1c56bdfff MPSMatrix arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSMatrix.framework/MPSMatrix
0x1c56be000 - 0x1c56d2fff MPSNDArray arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSNDArray.framework/MPSNDArray
0x1c56d3000 - 0x1c5868fff MPSNeuralNetwork arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSNeuralNetwork.framework/MPSNeuralNetwork
0x1c5869000 - 0x1c58aefff MPSRayIntersector arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSRayIntersector.framework/MPSRayIntersector
0x1c58af000 - 0x1c58affff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x1c58bc000 - 0x1c58bcfff MobileCoreServices arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x1c58c7000 - 0x1c58c8fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x1c58c9000 - 0x1c58cffff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x1c58d0000 - 0x1c58d5fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x1c590b000 - 0x1c5943fff QuickLookThumbnailing arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLookThumbnailing.framework/QuickLookThumbnailing
0x1c5d90000 - 0x1c5d90fff UIKit arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x1c6151000 - 0x1c62a6fff ANECompiler arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ANECompiler.framework/ANECompiler
0x1c62a7000 - 0x1c62b7fff ANEServices arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ANEServices.framework/ANEServices
0x1c62c0000 - 0x1c6351fff APFS arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/APFS.framework/APFS
0x1c6352000 - 0x1c6356fff ASEProcessing arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ASEProcessing.framework/ASEProcessing
0x1c650c000 - 0x1c6517fff AccountSettings arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x1c6e4a000 - 0x1c6e58fff AppleFSCompression arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleFSCompression.framework/AppleFSCompression
0x1c6e5f000 - 0x1c6e69fff AppleIDAuthSupport arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleIDAuthSupport.framework/AppleIDAuthSupport
0x1c6e6a000 - 0x1c6eacfff AppleJPEG arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x1c6ef7000 - 0x1c6f08fff AppleNeuralEngine arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleNeuralEngine.framework/AppleNeuralEngine
0x1c6f0f000 - 0x1c6f33fff AppleSauce arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSauce.framework/AppleSauce
0x1c7134000 - 0x1c7164fff Bom arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x1c7bf9000 - 0x1c7c00fff CommonAuth arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/CommonAuth
0x1c8044000 - 0x1c8048fff CoreOptimization arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreOptimization.framework/CoreOptimization
0x1c8193000 - 0x1c819efff DeviceIdentity arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DeviceIdentity.framework/DeviceIdentity
0x1c8335000 - 0x1c8351fff DocumentManagerCore arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DocumentManagerCore.framework/DocumentManagerCore
0x1c840a000 - 0x1c89e7fff Espresso arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Espresso.framework/Espresso
0x1c8ca9000 - 0x1c90bbfff FaceCore arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x1c9190000 - 0x1c91a4fff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
0x1c920b000 - 0x1c9217fff libhvf.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libhvf.dylib
0x1c9f64000 - 0x1c9f70fff GraphVisualizer arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphVisualizer.framework/GraphVisualizer
0x1ca295000 - 0x1ca306fff Heimdal arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Heimdal
0x1ca866000 - 0x1ca86cfff InternationalSupport arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/InternationalSupport.framework/InternationalSupport
0x1cab18000 - 0x1cab18fff Marco arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x1cb01c000 - 0x1cb02ffff MobileDeviceLink arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x1cb2ed000 - 0x1cb32dfff OTSVG arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OTSVG.framework/OTSVG
0x1cb9a1000 - 0x1cb9a1fff PhoneNumbers arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhoneNumbers.framework/PhoneNumbers
0x1cd31f000 - 0x1cd323fff RevealCore arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RevealCore.framework/RevealCore
0x1cd4b6000 - 0x1cd4c2fff SetupAssistantSupport arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SetupAssistantSupport.framework/SetupAssistantSupport
0x1cd4e1000 - 0x1cd4e1fff SignpostMetrics arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SignpostMetrics.framework/SignpostMetrics
0x1cde6a000 - 0x1cdf0dfff TextureIO arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextureIO.framework/TextureIO
0x1ceeaa000 - 0x1cf425fff libwebrtc.dylib arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/Frameworks/libwebrtc.dylib
0x1cf5cf000 - 0x1cf5d7fff kperfdata arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/kperfdata.framework/kperfdata
0x1cf5d8000 - 0x1cf621fff ktrace arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ktrace.framework/ktrace
0x1cf63a000 - 0x1cf646fff perfdata arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/perfdata.framework/perfdata
0x1cfa68000 - 0x1cfd99fff libAWDSupportFramework.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libAWDSupportFramework.dylib
0x1cff47000 - 0x1cff51fff libChineseTokenizer.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libChineseTokenizer.dylib
0x1cff77000 - 0x1d013bfff libFosl_dynamic.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x1d01b6000 - 0x1d01bdfff libMatch.1.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libMatch.1.dylib
0x1d027a000 - 0x1d027bfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1d0284000 - 0x1d0285fff libThaiTokenizer.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libThaiTokenizer.dylib
0x1d0385000 - 0x1d039afff libapple_nghttp2.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
0x1d0414000 - 0x1d0424fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x1d0425000 - 0x1d0431fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x1d0432000 - 0x1d0432fff libcharset.1.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libcharset.1.dylib
0x1d0433000 - 0x1d0444fff libcmph.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x1d0445000 - 0x1d045cfff libcompression.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x1d045d000 - 0x1d045efff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
0x1d045f000 - 0x1d0465fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x1d04a5000 - 0x1d04aefff libdscsym.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libdscsym.dylib
0x1d04f7000 - 0x1d04fcfff libheimdal-asn1.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib
0x1d04fd000 - 0x1d05effff libiconv.2.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x1d0605000 - 0x1d0610fff liblockdown.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x1d0611000 - 0x1d0629fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1d09b0000 - 0x1d09dffff libncurses.5.4.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
0x1d09e0000 - 0x1d09f5fff libnetworkextension.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libnetworkextension.dylib
0x1d0d7b000 - 0x1d0d93fff libresolv.9.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x1d0d94000 - 0x1d0d96fff libsandbox.1.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib
0x1d0d9d000 - 0x1d0dcffff libtidy.A.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x1d0dd7000 - 0x1d0ddafff libutil.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
0x1d0e08000 - 0x1d0e19fff libz.1.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x1d123a000 - 0x1d123ffff libcache.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x1d1240000 - 0x1d124cfff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x1d124d000 - 0x1d1250fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x1d1320000 - 0x1d1320fff liblaunch.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1d1321000 - 0x1d1326fff libmacho.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1d1327000 - 0x1d1328fff libremovefile.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1d1329000 - 0x1d132afff libsystem_featureflags.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib
0x1d132b000 - 0x1d1358fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1d1359000 - 0x1d135efff libunwind.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x1d1640000 - 0x1d16abfff NanoRegistry arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NanoRegistry.framework/NanoRegistry
0x1d16ac000 - 0x1d16b9fff NanoPreferencesSync arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NanoPreferencesSync.framework/NanoPreferencesSync
0x1d2120000 - 0x1d215bfff CryptoTokenKit arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework/CryptoTokenKit
0x1d2d97000 - 0x1d2da1fff PointerUIServices arm64e   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PointerUIServices.framework/PointerUIServices

EOF
```

my build settings:

[image]

Comment: it doesnt seem like there is any crash reported here or any warnings. Do you have any more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @sharkyenergy found the real bug! I am placing his solution above my suggestions:

"I developed on windows, but due to the pinch/zoom problem, i had to move to a mac. I didnt know that on mac you must add every nuget package to the .ios project too, while on windows they are shared. after adding all the packages it didnt crash anymore."

If his solution doesn't work for you, you can try the following below the line:

---

Things you can try,

1. While creating the archive, we use the `Release-iPhone` config, which is different from the `Release-iPhone Simulator` config. So when you are testing, you may not be testing the ACTUAL configuration. To check this, open the iOS Project Options in Visual Studio and compare all the settings to be the same (particularly the Linker behavior). Then test it on the simulator again and it could catch the error. [image: iOS Project Options in Visual Studio]

2.
Occasionally your app can crash on launch in prod only, and the Microsoft AppCenter package can help you with this for free. Here's something you can add in the `AppDelegate` just when your `FinishedLaunching` function begins:

```
AppCenter.Start(Constants.AppCenteriOSKey, typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
if (Crashes.HasCrashedInLastSessionAsync().Result)
{
    ErrorReport crashReport = Crashes.GetLastSessionCrashReportAsync().Result;
    if (crashReport.StackTrace == null)
        Analytics.TrackEvent("AppCrashedInLastLaunch: Crash Report Trace is Null");
    else
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("CrashId", crashReport.Id);
        dict.Add("StackTrace", crashReport.StackTrace);
        Analytics.TrackEvent(string.Format("AppCrashedInLastLaunch: " + crashReport), dict);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. there indeed were some differences between simulator and release.. now I have adapted the simulator, but still no crash... The code you posted, do I have to add it and just leave it there and it will add useful data to the crash report? or what does it do? Thank you

Comment: also, `AppCenter` and `Microsoft.Appcenter` do not exist in the current context.. it also shows no fixes..

Comment: ok, created the app in the appcenter, and added all dependencies and packages.. but crashReport.exception is depreciated and does not work..

Comment: @sharkyenergy Ah good to know, do you mean iPhone & iPhone Simulator in Release Config? Also about AppCenter, I hadn't updated my nuget packages. I updated my answer with non deprecated code

Comment: iPhone Simulator in debug config, and Iphone in release config.. I copied the Iphone Release config over to the debug simulator config.. but there are still no crashes..

Comment: Did you try iPhone Release config over to the iPhone Simulator Release config, and try it there?

Comment: I cant, becuase then I cannot submit it because of the `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type` setting.. I updated the main post with a screenshot of the settings I used

Comment: I am not asking you to submit it anywhere I'm just asking you to build on iPhone Simulator in release config with the same settings & properties. If you want I can try to build it on my phone for you-> my github username is saamerm. That might take lesser time. If you can't add the additional mtouch arguments, just remove it temporarily and see if it makes a difference. I have actually seen several Github issues where adding that mtouch arguments is causing crashes with some libraries @sharkyenergy

Comment: I found the bug! I developed on windows, but due to the pinch/zoom problem, i had to move to a mac. I didnt know that on mac you must add every nuget package to the .ios project too, while on windows they are shared. after adding all the packages it didnt crash anymore. Please, can you post it as answer, so at least you get the points for your help? you could leave your answer, and add this info at the top, since it contains very important informations.

Comment: @sharkyenergy I m glad you got it! And thank you for doing that, I updated my answer :)